# How can I incorporate a code for also counting number of sentences in a phrase? Python 3.X

Tags: python-3.x, word-count

I have created a code which counts the word count in a phrase and it works perfectly and I have an idea of how to code the sentence count put in not sure how to phrase it exactly or where to add it to the code I've already made. Can someone please help?

This is what I have done so far

```
def main():
    phrase = input("Enter a sentence:")
    words = phrase.split()
    wordCount = len(words)
    print("The total word count is: %s" % wordCount)
main()
```

This works perfecly but im not sure how to involve the code for character count or senctence count with this. I was trying to use character count so It will count the number of periods ('.') but im not sure where to place it and every time I do the code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a period marks the end of a sentence, you can get a count of all sentences by simply doing:

```
len(phrase.split('.')) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a code similar to this which counted periods but im uncertain of where exactly I place this

Comment: You place it wherever you want to get the length. For example, you can add this before your `print` line, as: `sentence_count = len(phrase.split('.')) - 1`. Then you can later `print` it or do whatever else you want with it.

Comment: This is certain to get you into trouble with most real-world applications, since there are unspaced ellipses (...) and sentences ending in ! or ?.  I suggest formulating regular expressions to get acquainted with that method, or for efficiency's sake at least using a lot more careful checks than looking for a '.'.

Answer (score 0):

`phrase.count('.')` gives you the number of periods (**not** the same thing as number of sentences as sentences can also end with `?` or `!`...!-) and `len(phrase)` the number of chars.  What you want to do with those is of course up to you!  Any spot after the initial `phrase =` statement is fine.